# how to make scrapy work

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to scrapy, and i follow tutorial but can't make it work.Every step is the same as the guidance. I wonder what is the problem?
i set the

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpca
```

and the spider is written as follows:

```
import re
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.http import Request
from adddelay.items import AdddelayItem


class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'adddelay'
allowed_domains = ['23us.com']
bash_url = 'http://www.23us.com//class/'
bashurl = '.html'

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        url = self.bash_url + str(i)+'_1' + self.bashurl
        yield Request(url, self.parse)
    yield Request('http://www.23us.com/quanben/1', self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

and repreat the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" ;part of the output as

```
2017-04-20 16:16:58 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.1 started (bot: adddelay)
2017-04-20 16:16:58 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['adddelay.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'adddelay', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 
'adddelay.spiders', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3, 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True}
2017-04-20 16:16:58 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-04-20 16:16:59 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.23us.com//class/1_1.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
return handler.download_request(request, spider)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 60, in download_request
return agent.download_request(request)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 285, in download_request
method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1631, in request
parsedURI.originForm)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1408, in _requestWithEndpoint
d = self._pool.getConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1294, in getConnection
return self._newConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1306, in _newConnection
return endpoint.connect(factory)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 788, in connect
EndpointReceiver, self._hostText, portNumber=self._port
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_resolver.py", line 174, in resolveHostName
onAddress = self._simpleResolver.getHostByName(hostName)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\resolver.py", line 21, in getHostByName
d = super(CachingThreadedResolver, self).getHostByName(name, timeout)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 276, in getHostByName
timeoutDelay = sum(timeout)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
2017-04-20 16:17:03 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.23us.com//class/2_1.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
return handler.download_request(request, spider)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 60, in download_request
return agent.download_request(request)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 285, in download_request
method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1631, in request
parsedURI.originForm)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1408, in _requestWithEndpoint
d = self._pool.getConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1294, in getConnection
return self._newConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1306, in _newConnection
return endpoint.connect(factory)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 788, in connect
EndpointReceiver, self._hostText, portNumber=self._port
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_resolver.py", line 174, in resolveHostName
onAddress = self._simpleResolver.getHostByName(hostName)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\resolver.py", line 21, in getHostByName
d = super(CachingThreadedResolver, self).getHostByName(name, timeout)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 276, in getHostByName
timeoutDelay = sum(timeout)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
2017-04-20 16:17:08 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.23us.com//class/3_1.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
return handler.download_request(request, spider)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 60, in download_request
return agent.download_request(request)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 285, in download_request
method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1631, in request
parsedURI.originForm)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1408, in _requestWithEndpoint
d = self._pool.getConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1294, in getConnection
return self._newConnection(key, endpoint)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 1306, in _newConnection
return endpoint.connect(factory)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 788, in connect
EndpointReceiver, self._hostText, portNumber=self._port
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_resolver.py", line 174, in resolveHostName
onAddress = self._simpleResolver.getHostByName(hostName)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\resolver.py", line 21, in getHostByName
d = super(CachingThreadedResolver, self).getHostByName(name, timeout)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 276, in getHostByName
timeoutDelay = sum(timeout)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
2017-04-20 16:17:12 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.23us.com//class/4_1.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
return handler.download_request(request, spider)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 60, in download_request
return agent.download_request(request)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 285, in download_request
method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
```

i forget that without an entrypoint, one couldn't debug scrapy in pycharm;the code should put at the your scrapy' root directory

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'adddelay'])
```

i have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this problem,the console raise this problem because of my scrpay's version is 1.0.x and the twisted'version is 17.1.1.One could solve this problem by install scrapy of 1.3.3. Scrapy of 1.3.3 works well with twisted of 17.1.1.